# Is a graph $H$ with different labelling a subgraph of $G$?

Tags: graph-theory

We know the definition of subgraph is as follows:

"If we have two graphs $G = ( V(G), E(G) )$ and $H =( V(H), E(H) )$, we say that $H$ is a subgraph of $G$ if $V(H)$ is a subset of $V(G)$ and $E(H)$ is a subset of $E(G)$."

Now, let's say that indeed H is a proper sub-graph of $G$, but now we decide to change the labellings of $H$ which means that $H$ is no longer a sub-graph of $G$ according to definition. However, we can absolutely say that $H$ is isomorphic to some sub-graph of $G$. Does this mean that $H$ is a sub-graph of $G$? -OR does it exactly mean: "$H$ is isomorphic to some sub-graph of $G$, but $H$ is not a subgraph."?

I am thinking that $H$ is not a subgraph of $G$ but it is indeed structurally same as some sub graph of $G$.

EDIT: Adding image for more clarity:
In each case $H$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $G$, is that correct?

But what about being a subgraph?

***CASE 1:*** $H$ is a subgraph of $G$.

***CASE 2:*** $H$ is not a subgraph of $G$ because we re-labelled vertices in a way
which added an edge that does not belong in vertex set of $G$ but we could have re-labelled $H$ in such a way that the re-labelling maintains the "subset property".

***CASE 3:*** $H$ is not a subgraph of $G$ because vertex set of $H$ is not a subset of vertex set of $G$.

***CASE 4:*** Not sure about this one because this is an unlabelled graph. Can we talk about "sub-graph" in the context of an unlabelled graph, or do we have to stick to "isomorphism"? My take is that "unlabelled" graph really means "isomorphism class of graphs" ( which include all the graphs with different labels / no labels, drawings of the same structure ) But since we need to emphasis on structure we use an "unlabelled" graph from that class. Meaning we can just replace this H with a labelled graph H from the isomophism class ~ which means we just have to logically label it so we preserve the "subgraph" relation so H is indeed a subgraph of G

***CASE 5:*** Similar logic to CASE 4, and yes H is indeed a subgraph of G

Not sure about case 4 and case 5, i don't know if we should be thinking in terms of isomorphism?

Can you guys tell me if my reasoning is correct?

[image]

Comment: Does it matter which leg you call "1" and which leg you call "4" if they're still holding up the same table in the same place? Either the vertex is in the graph or it is not. Relabelling doesn't change anything here.

Comment: @Nij added image for more clarity, can you take a look?

Comment: Identity, same vs isomorphic vs equal vs equivalent, identifier/name/label/reference, intension and extension, syntactic vs semantic, representation and meaning, ...

Comment: @Apass.Jack I am sorry but i don't understand your comment, can you elaborate further?